# How do I rewrite the url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could someone tell me how to rewrite this URL. I have looked at a lot of questions on stackoverflow but they seem to be missing my answer.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

That is what I have... its a bit poor.

I need to rewrite url's if they do not point to a directory.

I need to do this...

> any.domain.com/pages/some-page-slug/login

To be rewritten to the correct url of...

> any.domain.com/pages/login.php?page=32

Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What's the relationship between "some-page-slug" and "page=32"?

Answer (score 0):

1) Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product-12.html

It is a simple redirection in which .php extension is hidden from the browser’s address bar and dynamic url (containing “?” character) is converted into a static URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$1
```

2) Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product/ipod-nano/12.html

SEO expert always suggest to display the main keyword in the URL. In the following URL rewriting technique you can display the name of the product in URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$2
```

3) Redirecting non www URL to www URL

If you type yahoo.com in browser it will be redirected to www.yahoo.com. If you want to do same with your website then put the following code to .htaccess file. What is benefit of this kind of redirection?? Please check the post about SEO friendly redirect (301) redirect in php and .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^optimaxwebsolutions\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.optimaxwebsolutions.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

4) Rewriting yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz to yoursite.com/xyz

Have you checked zorpia.com.If you type http://zorpia.com/roshanbh233 in browser you can see my profile over there. If you want to do the same kind of redirection i.e http://yoursite.com/xyz to http://yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz then you can add the following code to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

5) Redirecting the domain to a new subfolder of inside public_html.

Suppose the you’ve redeveloped your site and all the new development reside inside the “new” folder of inside root folder.Then the new development of the website can be accessed like “test.com/new”. Now moving these files to the root folder can be a hectic process so you can create the following code inside the .htaccess file and place it under the root folder of the website. In result, www.test.com point out to the files inside “new” folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1
```

Comment: this is copied from the web. cite source please

Answer (score 0):

TO do this you need to write a front controller.

See [here](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php), [here](http://www.phpwact.org/pattern/front_controller), [here](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html), and [here](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-front).

Alternatively in Apache you can rewrite this

> any.domain.com/pages/32/login

or this:

> any.domain.com/32/login

or even this:

> any.domain.com/some-slug/32/login

to this:

> any.domain.com/pages/login.php?page=32

One way or another to do this with only apache you need to supply the page id in some fashion. Keep in mind even with format `any.domain.com/some-slug/32/login` the content of the slug is irrelevant and won't necessarily link to the correct page. Which I imagine is undesirable and bad for SEO.

**Another** alternative is using [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). But this will be tricky and require `reload`ing apache configurations whenever a page/slug is created/edit.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `pages` and `login` are static in this case and `some-page-slug` is changing. And you always want to redirect to static page `/pages/login.php?page=32`

So this is how to do it:

1) Rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/login(.*)$ /pages/login.php?page=32
```

or 2) Redirect Pernament

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/login(.*)$ /pages/login.php?page=32 [R=301,L]
```

or 3) Redirect Temporary

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/login(.*)$ /pages/login.php?page=32 [R=302,L]
```

Here is great article about htaccess trics
http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/